# Call a WebAPI in ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, markdown, asp.net-core-webapi

I have programmed a backend system in which I can manage data and then output it to an API. I did this because I want to convert a large project to a different language + framework, but I still want to integrate this backend system into the current version first, because it is much better than the old way. I have been looking for days how it works but I haven't really come to a result, I hope someone can help me.

example:
I have a separate page for each member with some data from a biography etc. and I can have this displayed in the WebAPI under: "https://sub.domain.de/items/member" then all members and associated data is output. Now I want that I to: "https://www.domain.de/member/[John_Doe]" (John_Doe is of course an example value for every other member)
can output certain data. the pages should of course still be generated dynamically.

ps: if it is necessary I can also enter "https://sub.domain.de/items/member/[John_Doe]" to only get the data from a specific member.

the json basically looks like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "John_Doe",
      "status": "published",
      "user_created": "052a2c25-b063-4a82-90cb-110d7f809cae",
      "date_created": "2021-06-29T08:30:06+02:00",
      "title": "Doc John Doe",
      "Characteristics": "- **Lorem **: ipsum dolor sit amet\n- **Birthdate**: 1965",
      "bio": "- **Lorem ipsum**:\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
      "member": true,
      "section1": false,
      "section2": false,
      "portrait": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Jane",
      "status": "published",
      "sort": null,
      "user_created": "052a2c25-b063-4a82-90cb-110d7f809cae",
      "date_created": "2021-06-29T08:29:31+02:00",
      "title": "Jane",
      "Characteristics": "",
      "bio": "Bio unbekannt.",
      "member": true,
      "section1": false,
      "section2": true,
      "potrait": "30d17fe3-bcf7-4aa2-9759-49f3e257eb0f"
    }
  ]
}
```

and the bio and the characteristics are written in markdown.

I hope I was able to explain what I mean and someone can help me.

edit:

ps: my main problem is that i don't know how to get data from an api, and of course i not only have the area with the members, i still have a lot of articles and more but it works with the same logic.

Comment: Pls show what code  have you done so far.

Comment: which code do you mean? my problem is that I don't know exactly how to get data from an api and display it in a view. I haven't written any code yet because I didn't get an answer anywhere.

Comment: @Serge Okay my Code is now: https://hastebin.com/opiyavovir.csharp

But when i get to the site, this error shows up:

https://prnt.sc/19kpwe4

Answer (score 0):

I guess this totally depending in the routing. you can construct your api that returned the data with this url :"https://sub.domain.de/items/member/[John_Doe]" like so

```
[Route("items/member")]
[ApiController]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{username}")]
    public IActionResult GetUserData(string username) {
    // your logic 
    } 
}
```

Comment: alright thanks! but i don't know exactly how i should call the api to get the data.

ps: I will display the member at the end with this url: "https://www.domain.de/member/xyz" but the url of the api is this: "https://sub.domain.de/items/ member / "

Comment: @Blizii you can just issue a GET HTTP request with the url you already sent " https://sub.domain.de/items/member/{username}" . if i answered your question just give me a vote.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry I'm a little too stupid to understand that, it's already pretty late for me .. so what exactly do I have to enter in the controller? and do i need a model? Because I don't want the route: "/items/member/John_Doe" on my website but only: "/member/John_Doe"

Comment: @Blizii regarding your question " so what exactly do I have to enter in the controller " i didn't get you at all, you mean what is the LINQ query you want to write to get user data ? what is the route you want to navigate it to access the api ??? and regarding your question " and do i need a model ?? " No you don't need .  and regarding that " Because I don't want the route: "/items/member/John_Doe" on my website but only: "/member/John_Doe" " you just can just put the route in the controller like so :

Comment: [Route("member")]
[ApiController]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{username}")]
    public IActionResult GetUserData(string username) {
    // your logic 
    } 
}

Comment: but i still have to enter the link of the API somewhere or not? The API is an isolated and independent project.

Comment: you should definitely enter the api link , ok i understand that the API is totally isolated but  you can access the action method you already create using the routing am already wrote to you

Comment: And do I have to add any logic or do I just copy the code into the controller and it works?

Comment: you can just copy your logic to the controller and if you build the logic well it will work flawlessly

Comment: but that is exactly my problem, i have no logic. i don't know exactly what to write in the logic